# Etymology of "end up" and "wind up"

Tags: etymology, verbs, phrasal-verbs

What is the etymology of the phrase "end up", and of the meaning of "wind up" that means essentially the same thing?

To clarify, I mean the *specific* meaning of "wind up" that means the same as "end up"

Like, you would say "[something] ends up [somewhere]" , and in at least some dialects you could say "[something] winds up [somewhere]" with the same meaning, and same with "[someone] ends up [doing something]".

In [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wind%20up), this sense is (intransitive verb) 1.b: "to arrive in a place, situation, or condition at the end or as a result of a course of action  " - and while "end up" has no dictionary entry, I've always thought of it as the "less unusual" way of saying the same thing.

Comment: "Turns out" is another synonym, leaning more toward resulting in the unexpected.

Answer (score 3):

Etymonline has these [notes on "wind"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wind):

> *Wind down* "come to a conclusion" is recorded from 1952; *wind up* "come to a conclusion" is from 1825.

The meaning is "to move by twisting and turning" and the relevant root is *windan*; the word is also related to *wend* and *wander*.

*End*, on the other hand, does have a different root [listed](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=end):

> O.E. *ende* "end, conclusion, boundary, district, species, class"

"End up" is not listed there. Searching for historical uses is mostly futile considering sentences such as "this end up" and "place the large end up". I am not sure there is any real link between the two. The relevant dictionary definition for "up" gives us a bit of a tip:

> up - to the place where someone is

The accompanying example is "creeping up" and within this framework you can see the use of "up" with many verbs that describe movement:

- creep up
- move up
- wind up
- end up
- jump up — slightly different
- drive up
- bike up
- go up
- walk up

And so on. Therefore, I suggest that the connection between "wind up" and "end up" has more to do with *up* than the other two words — even though they sound similar. Both *wind* and *end* have their histories and happen to work well with *up*.

Answer (score 1):

*Up* is often used as a modifier to indicate the successful execution of an action: *start up*, *finish up*, *clean up*, *settle up*. Typically, it connotes a sense of finality or completeness: you can *clean the house* as a process, but if you *clean up the house*, the implication is that you will clean until there is no more cleaning to be done (admittedly it usually doesn't work that way at my house).

Since *end* already indicates completion or finality, *end up* is redundant, and was probably coined as a mildly intensified synonym for "end," along the lines of the other examples  given above. It seems to be a relatively recent innovation; [examples of "end up" from the 19th century and earlier](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22end+up%22&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1500%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1899&tbm=bks) all seem to literally involve an end (of something) being elevated: "Four years ago I had a lot of pipe come which I judged must have been cast with the bell end up..."

*Wind up*, in the sense of "bring to a conclusion," is different. Merriam-Webster [dates](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wind%20up) the first known use to 1583. I would guess that it was initially used metaphorically, recalling the way one winds up a length of rope after using it for a task.

Comment: -1; I don't think "clean up" carries those implications at all and "end up" isn't redundant. It is a different phrase than "end" _or_ "up" and carries its own connotations.

Answer (score 0):

The semantic shift from 'wind up' to 'end up' appears obvious from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229183?rskey=IMK8nr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid1259964681)'s vertical juxtaposition of the meanings of 'wind up':

> #### to wind up
>
> **1.** *transitive*. To draw up or hoist with a winch or the like: cf. [19](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229183?rskey=IMK8nr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid14562859).
>
> **2.**
>
> **a.** †To bind or wrap up (*obsolete*); see also [16](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229183?rskey=IMK8nr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid14562218)  (quot. [1853 at sense 16a](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229183?rskey=IMK8nr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid14562397)).
>
> **3.**
>
> †**a.** To coil, roll, or fold up; to furl: cf. sense [15b](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229183?rskey=IMK8nr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid14562192). *Obsolete* except as in sense [16b(b)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229183?rskey=IMK8nr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid14562521).
>
> **b.** To coil (thread, etc.) into a compact mass (cf. [15](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229183?rskey=IMK8nr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid14562017)): chiefly in †to wind up a bottom or one's bottoms  ([bottom n. 24](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21923#eid16320923)), usually *figurative* to sum up, conclude (cf. sense [7d](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/229183?rskey=IMK8nr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid14560830)).